# Regex to detect consecutive lower and uppercase

Tags: r, regex

I have character vectors similar to this one:

```
test <- "ThisisAtest"
```

I would like to insert a `;` between lowercase and uppercase characters, so that the expected output is:

```
"Thisis;Atest"
```

To do so, I need to detect the consecutive lowercase and uppercase characters. I tried to do this (I used `str_remove` instead `str_replace` because I don't know the first pattern yet):

```
stringr::str_remove(test, "^[a-zA-Z]*$")
```

but it returns an empty character vector. Does anyone know how to do this?

I don't know if there are differences between the regex used by `gsub()` or `stringr::str_*` functions but I would prefer the latter.

Comment: You could use `gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", ";", test, perl=T)`

Comment: Use `stringr::str_replace_all(test, '(\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu})', '\\1;')` to also support any Unicode etters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use two capture groups here, one with lower case letter and another one which is immediately followed by upper case and put a semicolon in between.

Note that I have changed the string to include two occurrences of the pattern.

```
test <- "ThisisAtestAnew"

gsub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1;\\2', test)
[1] "Thisis;Atest;Anew"
```

This is similar to using `str_replace_all` in `stringr` :

```
stringr::str_replace_all(test, '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1;\\2')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also find the position between a lowercase char and an uppercase char using gsub and positive lookarounds without the anchors `^` and `$`

```
test <- "ThisisAtest"
gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", ";", test, perl=T)
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/FCUsTN)

Output

```
[1] "Thisis;Atest"
```

Answer (score 2):

One more fully Unicode-aware option is

```
stringr::str_replace_all(test, '(?<=\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu})', ';')
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\p{Ll}                Lowercase Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\p{Lu}                Uppercase Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take: Upper case letter followed for characters until another upper character, we are adding a ';' between two groups.

```
> test <- "ThisisAtest"
> gsub('([A-Z].*)([A-Z].*)','\\1;\\2',test)
[1] "Thisis;Atest"
>
```